# Django Clear Sessions and Flags every 20 mins

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on a Django Website in which whenever a user logs in it creates a session and in Models active is set to true  (`is_active=true`) when users logout the sessions clear and `is_active=false` for the user But the problem is when a User closes the tab/ browser instead of logging out
user is still said to be active .

**How to make a function which will logout all active users after 15 mins of  their login?**

Models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="None")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50,help_text="Minimum of 8 Characters")
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    authcode=models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    loginUser= request.session['username'] 
    if loginUser == '':
        return redirect('log')

    name= request.session['name']
    return render(request,'home.html')


def logot(request):
    loginUser=request.session['username'] 
    Employee.objects.filter(emp_id=loginUser).update(is_active=False)
    request.session['name']='';
    request.session['username']=''; 
    return redirect('welcome') 
# def scheduled_logout
   # Logout all user's after 15 mins of last_login
```

Comment: `is_active` does not mean the user is logged in! It means that this user _is allowed_ to login (does not matter whether they are logged in or not).

Comment: Also is there any particular reason you are not [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/)? Please read up on the linked documentation and use it. If you use the builtin authentication as linked you can set the [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) to log the user out after 15 mins as you want.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat         is_active is a field in my custom model I use it to check if user is logged in  and also use it to check current logged in users .  I have 2-3 models each with different fields its easier to create a Custom  Model